# Using Resolution rule from propositional logic for the xor expression

Tags: logical-operators, cs50, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

The XOR operation applied on two propositional Symbols P and Q could be defined as `(P or Q) and (Not(P) or Not(Q))`
But by using the resolution rule, `(P or Q) and (Not(P) or Not(Q))` would result in `(Q or Not(Q))`, which is always true.
I know this is incorrect, but I don't know where I went wrong in this logical deduction.